# Include file with function definitions Javascript Typescript

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, import, module

I am trying to create a new .ts file just to store some function definitions so that I do not have too much clutter on my main typescript file. I am struggling to figure out exactly how I should be defining it and incorporating the functions in my main file.

I have simplified my error as much as I can. Basically I have tried the following few ways:

---

Inside `functions.ts`

```
export module funcs{
  function testfunction( ):void {
    console.log('Succesfully called from the other file!');
  }
}
```

and then in `main.ts`

adding this line to reference that file:

```
/// <reference path="functions.ts" />
```

and this one when I am trying to call the function:

```
funcs.testfunction();
```

I've also tried importing the funcs module from the file, with no luck. I've tried writing the function definition outside of the export module.

I know that there is definitely an easier way to do this that I know I am overlooking, but I haven't been able to find anything that points it out clearly enough for me to get working.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to import the `funcs` module inside `main.ts`. Have you tried adding the following at the top of `main.ts` (instead of the `///` reference)?

```
import { funcs } from './functions';
```

It would also be helpful for you to share some more details about your situation. Exactly what error are you seeing, and when? How are you compiling and running your code?